# Mips, hexadecimal to binary conversion

Tags: assembly, low-level, mips32

I've been trying to do some conversion in mips assembly to try and turn hexadecimals to binary but I'm not sure how I would implement it. Here's the fragment of my code that's relevant to the conversion

```
    .data


operand: .asciiz "\nEnter correct value to be converted: "
result: .asciiz "\nYour result is: "
hexstore: .space 8

.globl main

.text
main:

li $v0, 4   #display welcome message
la $a0, welcome
syscall

li $v0, 5   #get int for type of operation
syscall

move $t0, $v0  #store result in t0, now compare t0 to t1 in order to get a branching result

addi $t1, $zero, 0 #set t1 to 0
addi $t1, $t1, 1 #set t1 to 1
beq $t0, $t1, hexatobinary #jump to hextobinary if t0 is 1
hexatobinary:

la $a0, operand     #prompt for input
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 5       #integer input
    syscall
    add $t0, $v0, $zero #Move to t0

    addi $t1, $zero, 0

    sw $t0, hexstore($t1)
```

So pretty much my thought process is to store the user inputted hex value, then try and read one bit at a time in a for loop and through 16 branches putting the correct binary values in a register, then after the loop is complete I would print the register and the conversion would complete. Is this the correct implementation? What code would I need in order to actually do that? Could i convert binary to hex through the same process? Thanks!

Comment: The read-int system call ([v0=5](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html)) already takes care of converting from an ASCII hex string to a binary integer in a register.  (If it supports hex at all?)  Hex is a text / human-readable serialization format for numbers.  Anyway yes, then you just need to isolate each binary bit in a register into `0`/`1` (usually with a shift / AND) and convert to ASCII `'0'` / `'1'`.  (Or use a print-int function to do that last part for you.)